# AWS DeepRacer fails to set up account resources, and I don't know why

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to give the AWS DeepRacer competition a try but It's not properly setting up my "Account resources" and I have no idea why.
This is what it's telling me:

[image]
 [image: image2]

These are the red errors:

```
Error in IAM role creation
Please try again after deleting the following roles: AWSDeepRacerServiceRole, AWSDeepRacerSageMakerAccessRole, AWSDeepRacerRoboMakerAccessRole, AWSDeepRacerLambdaAccessRole, AWSDeepRacerCloudFormationAccessRole.
```

```
There is an issue with your IAM roles
Unable to create all IAM roles
```

I have tried resetting the resources as it's telling me to do so.
But it still doesn't work afterwards. When I go to my IAM roles theres none of the described above. I have checked my account and everything else seems to be working fine. I checked and I can also manually create S3 buckets and IAM roles.

It's not giving me clear instructions on whats wrong or what I should do besides the ones on the image above so I'm not sure how to proceed!

Comment: The errors in the red boxes are too small to see, could you write them out?

Comment: Edited the original post, Thanks!

Comment: It's saying that the CloudFormation template is attempting to create resources with specific names, but those named resources already exist. Therefore, it is unable to create them and stack creation fails. Thus, it is asking you to delete the named roles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `IAM -> Roles` and delete following roles: 
AWSDeepRacerServiceRole
AWSDeepRacerSageMakerAccessRole
AWSDeepRacerRoboMakerAccessRole
AWSDeepRacerLambdaAccessRole
AWSDeepRacerCloudFormationAccessRole

Then try resetting Account Resources again